# How to show small am/pm instead of capital AM/PM in angularjs date filtering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, my requirement is I'm getting two dates from the sever, say `start_date` and `end_date`.

If the two dates are in 'pm', for example: `Sun 29 Jan 5.00 pm` to `Sun 29 Jan 6.00 pm`, I need show as "5.00 to 6.00 pm".

If `start_date` is in 'am' and `end_date` is in 'pm', I need to show them as "5.00 am to 6.00 pm". Additionally am/pm must be in small letters, not as AM/PM.

How do I do this?

Comment: try date: {{startDate: 'hh:mm a' | lowercase}} see this http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9597/

Comment: Or use CSS text transform on the container element: `text-transform: lowercase;`. ;-)

Comment: @Vinod, thanks, it works for me

Comment: @RobG, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like

```
<div>{{startDate: 'hh:mm a' | lowercase}} to {{endDate: 'hh:mm a' | lowercase}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, but it showing as 5.00 AM , i need to show as 5.00 am ,in smaller letters i need  to show

Comment: Try using lowecase filters on the result

Comment: Thanks @Ali Baig, it works, and how can i show if both start_date and end_date is in am/pm , then 5.00 to 6.00 am/pm , if different then 5.00 am to 6.pm

Comment: @AndrewD. Since the format he has given which is all numbers, we can afford to use it here.

Comment: @ShaikHabeeb You can remove `a` from the format of start date but that won't ensure the case of 4:00 am to 6:00 pm for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Date = {{ today | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a' | lowercase }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it in lower by using default [lowercase](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/lowercase) for case operation.

```
{{'1288323623006' | date:"h.mm"}} {{'1288323623006' | date:"a" | lowercase}} to {{'1288373623006' | date:"h.mm"}} {{'1288373623006' | date:"a" | lowercase}}
```

[this](http://plnkr.co/edit/zc2ef0G3OTycB3VbqeQn) is an updated answer..